# How to invalidate visual on dependency property changed?

Tags: .net, wpf, controls, dependency-properties

I have custom control with overridden *OnRender* method.
I would like to invalidate control on any dependency property changed event. Also would be nice to update when properties of the parent type are changed.
Any way to do this with the built in features?

**Edit:**

I have found that I can use both 'affect render' for a dependency properties and check on  OnLayoutUpdated for the additional information or private properties if any.

```
FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsRender
```

and:

```
private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int result = (CornerRadius != null ? CornerRadius.GetHashCode() : 0);
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (IsSelected.GetHashCode());
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (IsReadCornerRadiusFromConfig.GetHashCode());
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (IsReadBorderThicknessFromConfig.GetHashCode());
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (SelectedColor!=null?SelectedColor.GetHashCode():0);
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (Background != null ? Background.GetHashCode() : 0);
        result = (result * PrimeHashNumber) ^ (BorderBrush != null ? BorderBrush.GetHashCode() : 0);
        
        if (lastHash != result)
        {
            this.InvalidateVisual();
            lastHash = result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't use LayoutUpdated for that, because it gets way more frequentely fired than you might expect. It is called so often that it "feels" like the right place, but you might get into some performance issues while using this.

Comment: @dowhilefor that why hash is calculated. I dont see other way because i need to track different internal properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

imho the best approach is that specify on the DependencyProperties that you use, that they affect rendering.

See FrameworkPropertyMetadata.AffectsRender: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The quickest of course would be to go the dirty way and do this

```
(DataContext as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += OnPropertiesChanged

private void OnPropertiesChanged(sender, args)
{
    InvalidateVisual();
}
```

But i strongly advise you not to do something like that. The imho much better solution is on the other hand a bit restricted. Try to change your custom dependency properties so that they are relevant to the rendering, for that you can supply the flag [AffectsRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadataoptions.aspx) when creating the dependency properties.
Now you are saying "properties from parent type" i don't get that part but i guess you mean a parent view model with a child view model. This shouldn't matter if you design your properties accordingly.
If for some reason that solution doesn't work, you could use just one property on the view model, bound to an dependency property with the AffectsRender flag in the view and just set it in your view model logic when the view should redraw, but again this is imho the dirty way.

Also don't get too tempted to do a lot of drawing with the OnRender method, we use WPF in a large application and we have maybe one or two places were we are using the OnRender, everything else is accomplished with styles and templates.

Comment: I also was busy with few big projects and almoust all UI was done with styles and templates. But if you want to draw charts or something really complex you have to use OnRender in other case performance will be really bad.

Comment: That is true, but if performance is really that important, i would skip "controls" alltogether. While you still can get a lot of performance out of Visuals, maybe [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) might be also worth considering.

Answer (score 1):

If your control's size doesn't change, `InvalidateVisual()` is extremely expensive, as it causes a full relayout of the control tree.

If the size is staying the same, it is much more efficient to use the fact that some retained mode drawing objects can be updated *after* they are output during `OnRender()`. For example, `DrawingGroup`, `WriteableBitmap`, and `RenderTargetBitmap` can all be updated *after* they are output during `OnRender()`.

In most cases, you would create a `DrawingGroup` "backingStore", output it during `OnRender()` and then you can update the visual of your control any time by doing `backingStore.Open()` and putting new drawing commands into the `DrawingGroup`.